# Formatting SMS inbox date showing as "Jan 1st 1970"

Tags: java, android

I'm building an app that's using the SMS features in Android Studio and what I am trying to do is display the date and time the SMS was sent/received. I'm using a cursor to read the sms inbox data from the phone and display it in the listview which it is doing it but it is displaying as "Thr Jan 01 10:30:01 LHST 1970" and not the actual date sent/received from the phone.

I've tried formatting it using the other methods found here but they all made the app crash when I tried to run it.

[image]

Here's the code of the SMS inbox being read in by the cursor and being displayed in the listview.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");

ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
String phoneNumber = "0409579347";
String sms = "address='"+ phoneNumber + "'";
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, new String[] {"_id", "body", "date"}, sms, null, null);

System.out.println ( cursor.getCount() );

while(cursor.moveToNext())
{
    String strbody = "Command: " + cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex("body")) + "\n";

    String date = "\nDate: " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date")) + "\n";

    Date formatted_date = new Date(cursor.getLong(0));

    String displayDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy").format(formatted_date);

    System.out.println ( strbody );
    System.out.print(displayDate);

    arrayAdapter.add(strbody + formatted_date);
}
```

Comment: Any time you see January 1, 1970, you're getting a zero for a date.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, by using [SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat).

```
 SimpleDateFormat mdFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
 Date formatted_date = new Date();
 String displayDate = mdFormat.format(formatted_date);
 System.out.print(displayDate);
```

Comment: Hey thanks man but there's still a little problem with this solution, it's showing today's date for all of them instead, not the actual date/time it was actually sent.